# Word HTML page break won't work if using mso footer

Tags: html, css, ms-word

I want to add a footer to my HTML-generated Word .doc files, but if I use the code that's out there I lose my page break control.

For example:

In the  header I have 'mso-footer: f1;' in the @page Section 1 tags

In the  header I have:

```
p.MsoFooter, li.MsoFooter, div.MsoFooter
{
 margin:0in;
 margin-bottom:.0001pt;
 mso-pagination:widow-orphan;
 tab-stops:center 3.0in right 6.0in;
 font-size:12.0pt;
}
```

Just after my normal HTML table stuff I've inserted:

```
strHtmlFooter = strHtmlFooter & "<div style='mso-element:footer' id=f1>"
strHtmlFooter = strHtmlFooter & "<p class='MsoFooter'>"
strHtmlFooter = strHtmlFooter & "<span style='mso-tab-count:2'>Fred Smith</span>"
strHtmlFooter = strHtmlFooter & "</p>"
strHtmlFooter = strHtmlFooter & "</div>"
```

and then after this I have the line:

```
strHtmlFooter = strHtmlFooter & "<BR CLEAR='ALL' STYLE='mso-special-character:line-break;page-break-before:always'>"
```

If I run the above I get a MS Word doc with a footer on, but none of my page breaks works.

If I take out the page footer div then the page breaks come back.

Any ideas how I can have both??

Thanks

Comment: Word's round-trip HTML file format is undocumented and unsupported. You could *try* saving a Word document with the characteristics you're having trouble with (small as possible) as unfiltered HTML then look at the HTML...

Comment: Hi Cindy, thanks for coming back to me.  Could not find a way round it so had to do it the Word xml way.  Works far better.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to suggest Word Open XML, but decided you must know why you want to go the HTML route...